# Include file from URL parameter?

Tags: php

This is how I normally include files:

```
<?php include 'paypal/file.php'; ?>
```

However, I need to get the `service` parameter from my URL and match it with the correct file to be included.  For example, the page `mywebsite.com/?service=12345` should include this file:

```
<?php include 'paypal/12345.php'; ?>
```

What would I need to do to reference the URL parameter in my statement like that?

Comment: **BIG SECURITY RISK**

Comment: Why would that be a big security risk?  All that any of the PHP files contain in them is the code for a PayPal button...

Comment: Because the user can put whatever they want in the parameter like `../../../somefile`. Just because you made a link that only puts a numeric code in there doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Ohh so basically you're saying they could use it to include a file that I didn't want them to because I'm referencing the parameter?  Or am I wrong about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php include 'paypal/' . $_GET['service'] . '.php'; ?>
```

Should do it, but (like John commented), this is a huuuge security risk. If you end up doing this, be sure to sanitize your input first!

Comment: Should probably include about a whitelist to run the get parameter against ensuring its valid ;-)

Comment: ...`if(in_array){...}`

Answer (score 0):

1 - get the data from the url with `$service = isset($_GET['service']) ? $_GET['service'] : '';`

2 - scan your includes dir and check if there is a file matching the url

```
$scan = scandir('paypal/');

$offscan = array('.','..','.htaccess','.DS_Store','thumbs.db'); //etc depends what you can have in there

if( !in_array($service, $offscan) && in_array($service, $scan) && !is_dir('paypal/'.$service) ){
    include 'paypal/'.$service.'.php';
}
else{
    die('This service does not exists');
}
```

But as John told you in comments, this is still a security risk. Best way would be to get from database a list of whitelisted "services", and accept only them.